# XFCE ignoring icons set in /usr/share/applications/

Tags: xfce, icons

I set the icon for atom in `/usr/share/applications/atom.desktop` using

```
Icon=atom
```

and

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Paper/512x512/apps/atom.png
```

Either way, the icon looks right in the `.desktop` file but when I double click it, the icon in the `windows buttons` item in the panel and the icon in the tab switcher is still the default one. How do I fix this?

Comment: What distro are you using? And did you install it manually or using the package manager.

Comment: Arch. I installed atom with yaourt.

Comment: Just tested it with another app, and the window buttons and tab switcher keep using the default theme icons. :(